# I have 3 parameters and I keep getting the forward dependencies are not valid error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

> The report parameter 'ServicePriorityNameParameter' has a DefaultValue
>   or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter
>   "ServicePriorityNameParameter". Forward dependencies are not valid.

This is the error I keep receiving when trying to use this parameter.

I also have a WorkCategoryParameter which I specified the values for. Also a RequestNumberParameter in which a request number can be typed into.

I have tried reordering my parameters and also adding a separate dataset in which to run each parameter off of. I'm pretty new to SSRS so any words of advice will help. Thanks!

Comment: Please, edit you question to include the SQL for the datasets you are using to populate you parameter available values. A screenshot showing the order of the parameters in the designer would be helpful, too. You are currently not providing enough information for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reordering the parameters in the designer does not actually reorder them. If you open the report's rdl file (if using visual studio just right-click the report in the solution explorer and select View Code). In there, look for the ReportParameters section and reorder the parameters from there. Basically you need to make sure that any parameters that are dependent on other parameters are listed after the thing they are dependant on.

E.g. If you had a parameter called @`Countries` to list countries based on continent and the dataset that supplied the values to that parameter read something like `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyCountryTable WHERE Continent = @continent` then the `@continent` parameter would have to appear first in the list as `@Countries` depends on it.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me fix this and I was scratching my head for a couple hours over this yesterday.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Could you kindly mark the answer as accepted. If not others will see this listed as an unanswered question.